# Parsing XML with missing nodes

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I have an XML file with orders.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<orders>
<order order-no="1234567">
    <order-date>2012-09-15T12:28:45.000Z</order-date>
    <invoice-no>123</invoice-no>
    <customer>
        <customer-no>1234</customer-no>
        <customer-name>test</customer-name>
    </customer>
    <payments>
        <payment>
            <custom-method>
                <method-name>example</method-name>
            </custom-method>
            <amount>12334</amount>
        </payment>
    </payments>
</order>
<order>
   .......
</order>
</orders>
```

Many `<order>` nodes in one file. Everything is correct but then out of the blue I get an order without any payment information like this

```
<orders>
<order order-no="1234567">
    <order-date>2012-09-15T12:28:45.000Z</order-date>
    <invoice-no>123</invoice-no>
    <customer>
        <customer-no>1234</customer-no>
        <customer-name>test</customer-name>
        <billing-address/>
    </customer>
    <payments/>
</order>
```

Notice the empty `<payments/>` node.
My PHP script looks like this:

```
$file = file_get_contents('orders.xml');
$orders = new SimpleXMLElement($file);
foreach ($orders as $order) {
    $var = $order->payments->payment->{'custom-method'}->{'method-name'};
}
```

With the first XML example everything is fine but when I stumble upon an order from a second XML example my script is throwing an exception `Trying to get property of non-object` and obviously stops parsing the rest of the file.
I'd like my script to **not** stop and just go on with parsing the rest of the file. I don't want to you the "shut up" `@` operator, but I don't see any other way.

Comment: Why don't you test if `payments` is an object before accessing its member `payment`?

Comment: I save data from that file in DB and there's about 40 nodes tat I check. Do you suggest adding some function with `property_exists`?

Comment: I was answering to this specific case. If you have a lot of code handling this and multiple nodes can go missing you could look at http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.simplexmliterator.php. I'm not sure why you don't check each level before accessing it if you XML could be "uncomplete". Did you try catching this  speficic exception ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add logic to ensure `<payments>` has payment data (i.e. `payment` nodes).

```
foreach ($orders as $order) {
    if ($order->payments->count()) {
        // has payment data... run your payment code
    }
}
```

#### UPDATE

Even though the [docs claim](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.count.php) the above should work with PHP > 5.3, it returned `1` in the OP's case (not sure why).

Ultimately the following is needed:

```
count($order->payments->children())
```

Comment: `$order->payments->count()` returns 1 but `<payments/>` has no children?

Comment: What version of PHP are you running?

Comment: PHP Version 5.3.1 which according to documentation should be ok `(PHP 5 >= 5.3.0)`

Comment: Just found out that
$order->payments->count() returns 1
but
$order->payments[0]->count() returns 0

Comment: I'm sure there's a straightforward explanation. I'm not as close to the code as you.

Comment: @JasonMcCreary: `$order->payments->payment->count()` is `0`, `$order->payments->count()` is `1`, because there is one `<payments>` element. - more explanations: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14755078/367456

Comment: @hakre, then the docs are misleading in their example… Thanks for the additional explanation though.

Comment: The example in the docs is fine, there is just a difference between `$element->count()` (example in the docs) and `$element->nameChildren->count()` (not covered in the docs). The first does not name the children elements you want to count, the second does. If you name the children elements, and the parent elements are more than one, only the first parent element will be taken. SimpleXML has a magical interface, so it's not that distinct.

Answer (score 0):

SimpleXML comes with some bunch of *magic*. Let's see how you access the (existing or non-existing) `<payment>` element:

```
$order->payments->payment
```

This will (always!) result in a `SimpleXMLElement` regardless if the count of `<payment>` elements inside `<payments>` elements is zero or larger.

However, if the count is actually zero, accessing the first `<payment>` element will return `NULL`:

```
$order->payments->payment[0]
```

This is accessing the first (zero-based index in SimpleXML) payment element. As it does not exist, this results in `NULL`. So you can if-check this:

```
foreach ($orders as $order) 
{
    if (!$order->payments->payment[0]) 
        continue;

    $var = $order->payments->payment->{'custom-method'}->{'method-name'};
}
```

The other answer suggested to use the [`SimpleXMLElement::count()`](http://php.net/SimpleXMLElement.count%28%29) method. It counts the children of an element and it works as well, however the other answer suggested the wrong place to use it, the correct place is with the `<payment>` element(s), not the `<payments>` element:

```
$order->payments->payment->count()
```

This returns the `0` (zero) number of elememnts you wanted to check for. So this is working equally well:

```
foreach ($orders as $order) 
{
    if (!$order->payments->payment->count()) 
        continue;

    $var = $order->payments->payment->{'custom-method'}->{'method-name'};
}
```

However this excursion would not be complete to actually show you a way that is probably most intended with `SimpleXMLElement`. It is based on the fact that an empty `SimpleXMLElement` equals false:

```
foreach ($orders as $order) 
{
    if (!$order->payments->payment) 
        continue;

    $var = $order->payments->payment->{'custom-method'}->{'method-name'};
}
```

As all these examples show, you need explore SimpleXML a little to understand it's magic so you can benefit from it.

If you prefer an interface with less magic, checkout the sister [`DOMDocument`](http://php.net/DOMDocument).

And independent to `SimpleXMLElement`, whenever you've got a `Traversable` (which it is as well), you can make use of a function called [`iterator_count`](http://php.net/iterator_count) to give back the count of iterations. For a `SimpleXMLElement` it means the number of children.